# Inserir dados por PHP

Tags: php, sql, sql-insert

Depois de submeter o formulário faço o seguinte:

```
 $n_processo = $_POST['n_processo'];
 $nome = $_POST['nome'];
  $dia = $_POST['dia'];
  $mes=$_POST['mes'];
  $ano = $_POST['ano'];
  $data = $dia."-".$mes."-".$ano;
    $cc = $_POST['cc'];
    $curso =$_POST['cursos'];
  $ciclo1 = $_POST['ciclo'];
  $ciclo2 = $_POST['ciclo2'];
  $ciclo = $ciclo1."-".$ciclo2;` 


    $sqlcurso = mysql_query("SELECT n_curso FROM cursos WHERE designacao LIKE '".$curso."'");

    $row = mysql_fetch_array($sqlcurso);    


    $sql = "INSERT INTO alunos(n_processo,nome,data_nasc,cc,n_curso,ciclo_formacao)
          VALUES ('".$n_processo."','".$nome."','".$data."','".$cc."','".$row['n_curso']."','".$ciclo."')";

    if(!mysql_query($sql))
    {
        echo"1";
    }
    else
    {
        $sql2 = mysql_query("SELECT n_processo FROM alunos WHERE n_processo = '".$n_processo."'");
      $sql22 = mysql_num_rows($sql2);

      if($sql22 > 0)
      {
        echo "2";
      }
      else
      {
        echo "3";
      }
  }
```

Fiquei confuso porque supostamente o ponto de exclamação(!) significa diferente como na query acima indica quando a query não funcionou,
dava uma mensagem, em baixo fazia a query para ver se já existe algum registo com aquela chave primária, se existir da a mensagem 2 senão dá a mensagem 3 que quer dizer que foi inserido com sucesso, mas só é inserido quando retorna a mensagem 2 que significa que já existe?
Estarei a baralhas as coisas?

Comment: Você notou tem que um ` fora de lugar ali né? Seu código não é seguro, está usando uma função obsoleta e, além disso, está totalmente aberto a ataques SQL Injection. E sim, sua dúvida ficou bem confusa. Tente editar e separar as dúvidas por partes, uma por uma ou simplesmente nos diga o problema / o que deseja fazer.

Comment: Ola, o echo 1 vai ser quando der erro. O echo 2 vai aparecer quando nao der erro. O echo 3 nunca vai aparecer porque vai sempre existir. Era a sua questao?

Comment: Clayderson, queria perceber o porquê de aparecer a mensagem 2 em vez da 3, mas como o Tiago disse, o 3 vai exisitir sempre. Porque? Na query se nao existir nenhum dado vai ser = 0 então nao devia aparecer a mensagem 3 e nao a 2 não é?

Comment: Ola, @programmer2016 vai sempre existir porque é feito um insert antes.